# Intellij Idea auto replace on the fly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am looking for a plugin for IntelliJ Idea or an unknown built-in feature which is similar to Microsoft Word auto replace. It replaces letters while you are typing according to a replacement table.

I could achieve the same with altering keyboard layout on system level, but I'd like to solve the problem in an easier way.

The idea behind this is that if you remap "(){}_@"" to "90[]-2'" and vise versa, then you press less keys (4%) because in an average Java project symbol frequency differs from the global symbol frequency and I am lazy to press Shift extra time while I am typing Java code.

Comment: which os are you using ?

Comment: Ubuntu and I know how to remap there, but it's not efficient because remapping have sense only for typing Java.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/97213/application-specific-key-combination-remapping

Answer (score 2):

After I wasn't able to find anything existing and I created a simple
concept plugin which does this remapping.

https://github.com/yaitskov/type-less